# Routing WebApi through Point-to-Site and Site-to-site on Azure

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, gateway

i have a webAPI hosted on azure. It connects to 3rd party site using their dev env IPAddress and Port. This works fine. The requirement was to then create site-to-site VPN connection to connect to their live env.

I created a VNet,vNetGateway and localGateway. the VnetGateway using a new public IP that connects successfully to their localGateway.

Then i want to route my webAPI through the vNetGateway so i setup the point-to-site configuration.

My webAPI is making a socket connection internally pointed at their subnet address and port they specified but all i can see is conn errors.

What is the web address and port the webApi should be connecting to?

Comment: Are you able to pass traffic to/from the tunnel in any other capacity? My first guess is the vNet firewall's ingress settings, or if the live site has a firewall there may be egress rules there stopping the traffic.

Comment: There is no firewall on the vNet. the 3rd party site has whitelisted our gateway so the connection between them is fine. im not sure how to debug the connection between my api and vnet.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I see you stuck in

> how to debug the connection between my api and vnet

In this case, many methods you can do to debug the connection between API and vnet.

- Create a virtual machine in the vnet and try to connect from or to the web app.
- Use the kudu console and try to ping your client or virtual machine. eg, ping a VM using `tcpping 10.10.0.4:3389`
- Execute a web request to one of your servers or your client.

You can get more details from this wonderful blog: [Connect Azure App Service to virtual network](https://codehollow.com/2016/12/connect-azure-app-service-to-virtual-network/)

Comment: Is this helpful?